# Console API - Sidebars IDs

Tags: consoleintegrationtoolkit

We're trying to show/hide some console sidebars components.
Looking through the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_setsidebarvisible.htm), we found the following method signature:

```
sforce.console.setSidebarVisible( visible:Boolean, (optional)tabId:String, (optional)region:String, (optional)callback:Function)
```

... and an call example:

```
sforce.console.setSidebarVisible(true,'scc-st-1',sforce.console.Region.LEFT,callback);
```

We were wondering from where the `scc-st-1` ID was taken/generated?
Is there a predefined list of IDs based on the components positioning or are these IDs generated dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scc-st-0`, `scc-st-1`... `scc-st-x` are ids of the subtabs on the current primary tab. These Ids are generated dynamically. You can find the list of subtabs available in the primary tab using Chrome developer tools. I have seen the ids are generated sequentially in the order they have opened `scc-st-0`, `scc-st-1`... `scc-st-x` irrespective of the primary tab.

Using Inspection Tool

[image]

Using JavaScript Console

[image]